# firebase functions sending bad request

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the json data from an external api and save it in the firebase firestore database. When I run the function I get the following error

my error log

`$ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'borsa-app-f6921'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

```
 > lint
 > eslint .

  +  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
  i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
  i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
  i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
  +  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
  +  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
  +  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
  i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
  !  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions.
  Please upgrade-using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
  !  functions: Please note that there will be breaking changes when you upgrade.
  i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
  i  functions: packaged C:\Users\yusuf\Desktop\bulut-fonksiyonlari\functions
  (75.69 KB) for    uploading
  +  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully

  The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
    myFunction(us-central1)

   If you are renaming a function or changing its region, 
   it is recommended that you create the new function first before deleting the old one 
   to prevent event loss. For more info, visit https://firebase.google.
   com/docs/functions/manage- functions#modify

 ? Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest of
 the deployments. Yes
 i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function saveDataToFirestore(us-central1)...
 i  functions: deleting Node.js 16 function myFunction(us-central1)...
 +  functions[myFunction(us-central1)] Successful delete operation.
 Build failed: ...lid: lock file's google-p12-pem@3.1.4 does not satisfy google-p12-pem@2.0.5
 npm ERR! Missing: node-forge@0.10.0 from lock fi le
 npm ERR! Missing: has-tostringtag@1.0.0 from lock file
 npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's yallist@4.0.0 does not satisfy yallist@3.1.1
 npm ERR! Missing: define-properties@1.1.4 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: has-property-descriptors@1.0.0 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: mimic-fn@2.1.0 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: duplexify@4.1.2 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: functions-have-names@1.2.3 from lock file
 npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's http-proxy-agent@5.0.0 does not satisfy http-proxy-agent@4.0.1
 npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's uuid@8.3.2 does not satisfy uuid@7.0.3
 npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @tootallnate/once@2.0.0 does not satisfy @tootallnate/once@1.1.2
 npm ERR! Missing: is-bigint@1.0.4 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: is-boolean-object@1.1.2 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: is-number-object@1.0.7 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: is-symbol@1.0.4 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: has-bigints@1.0.2 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: is-weakmap@2.0.1 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: is-weakset@2.0.2 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: available-typed-arrays@1.0.5 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: for-each@0.3.3 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: gopd@1.0.1 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: is-typed-array@1.1.10 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: is-callable@1.2.7 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: p-try@2.2.0 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: core-util-is@1.0.3 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: isarray@1.0.0 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: process-nextick-args@2.0.1 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: safe-buffer@5.1.2 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: string_decoder@1.1.1 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/auth-interop-types@0.1.5 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@0.3.2 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.1.19 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/database-types@0.5.2 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: tslib@1.14.1 from lock file
 npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app-types@0.6.1 from lock file
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Clean install a project
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Usage:
 npm ERR! npm ci
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Options:
 npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
 npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
 npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
 npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
 npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
 npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
 npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2022-12-14T11_02_18_814Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

 Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        saveDataToFirestore(us-central1)
   i  functions: cleaning up build files...
  !  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small 
  monthly       bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images
  by redeploying or you can delete them manually  
  at https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/borsa-app-f6921/us-central1/gcf-artifacts

  Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

this is my code

```
  const functions = require("firebase-functions");
  const admin = require("firebase-admin");
  const axios = require("axios");

  admin.initializeApp();

  const db = admin.firestore();

   exports.saveDataToFirestore = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     axios.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets? vs_currency=usd&order
       =market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true")
        .then((res) => {
          db.collection("data").add(res.data)
            .then(() => {
              response.send("successful");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               response.send("Error " + err);
            });
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         response.send("Error REST API: " + err);
       });
   });
```

Comment: which versions of `firebase-admin` and `firebase-functions` are you using? Can you share `package.json` of your functions folder ?

Comment: You can access it from my Github repository.

Comment: https://github.com/yusuff122/bulut-fonksiyonlari

Comment: I posted an answer. You can check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your node to 14 instead of 16, let me know if it worked.
If 14 doesn't work, put any of 12 or 10. As you are using firebase 8, this might a compatibility issue

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.13.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Following is a workable package.json

```js
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^4.8.1",
    "@google-cloud/logging": "^9.2.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.3.0",
    "@google-cloud/tasks": "^2.3.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.15.7",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

You can try installing the versions here of firebase, firebase-admin and firebase-functions, this is working for my project. I can deploy the functions. Do an `npm install` before deploying

Update the function like the following

```js
exports.saveDataToFirestore = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     axios.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets? vs_currency=usd&order
       =market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=true")
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("res.data", res.data); // make sure you check logs for this, you have make sure you res.data is not undefined
          // we need a unique identified, I will use timestamps
          const id = new Date().getTime(); // this will be unique
          db.collection("data").doc(id).set(res.data,{merge: false}) // this will create a new doc
            .then(() => {
              response.send("successful");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               response.send("Error " + err);
            });
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         response.send("Error REST API: " + err);
       });
   });
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: can you remove the devDependencies, see the updated answer now, do a `npm install` before deploying, also use 12 for node

Comment: i  functions: updating Node.js 12 function saveDataToFirestore(us-central1)...Error: There was an error deploying functions

Comment: Can you post the full error in the post, after updating to Node 12

Comment: I updated and added

Comment: it worked but my data doesn't show up in the database

Comment: okay so, you function getting deployed now, right? Now, the problem is function isn't updating firestore, correct ?

Comment: I upadated my answer again, you can check now. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't see the data, it looks like I did something wrong with the database.
 I have attached a photo of the database, could you please have a look?

Comment: Do you have kind of id in res.data?

Comment: I'm a firebase database newbie, I went through the blaze plan and set up the database that I took a photo of, I couldn't do anything else

Comment: okay check my updated answer now, I have used timestamp as a unique id for each document. Should work this time !

Comment: and make sure to run your API in POSTMAN or anyway to see what kind of data is returns
`res.data` has to be an object for this to work properly

Comment: sorry for making you tired, i want data from external api to be added to firestore database, they are not connected to database, empty as in photo